# If I disable iptables its working. Which rule is making my websites a timeout?

Tags: linux, networking, firewall, iptables, tcp

I have a VPS with nginx but no website is working and timeout is sent. When I disable iptables everything is fine. But no idea which rule/s is taking the problem. Any help?

```
$sudo iptables -S
-P INPUT ACCEPT
-P FORWARD ACCEPT
-P OUTPUT ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p icmp -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
-A OUTPUT -p tcp -m tcp --sport 443 -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -p tcp -m tcp --sport 80 -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

Both 443 and 80 dport and sport rules are new. Tried as read in a website to open the ports with no success.

Answer (score 0):

The order of the rules is important. The first matching rule will be used. In your case `REJECT` comes before `ACCEPT`.

You should consider (generally a good idea) to move a conditionless `REJECT` to the end of the chain.

Answer (score 0):

REJECT rule in the INPUT chain is matching all incoming packets so it should be placed at the end of your chain.
So sequence change will fix the issue :

1- Save the existing iptables

```
sudo iptables-save > /tmp/iptables.txt
```

2- Edit the text file to change the order

```
sudo vi /tmp/iptables.txt
```

3- Restore the edited rules

```
sudo iptables-restore < /tmp/iptables.txt
```